# Angular $q.defer() returns Object{then: function}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular file, where I try to access a database with $http, and then use this data in a $scope variable (to display in the webpage). The trouble is I can't get $q.defer to run as I believe it should. The console.log() inside the $http function logs an object containing the data returned from the database. However when I call the function it logs `Object {then: function}`. The data is contained within this object, but it is not the only part of the object. (It seems like it's in Object.$$v. I'm not sure what that means.)

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.factory('portfolioFactory', function ($http, $q) {
        var obj = {};
    obj.getResponse = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('./../includes/portfolio/db_access.php').success(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
                console.log(data);
        });
        //console.log(deferred.promise);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    return obj;
});

app.controller("PortfolioCtrl", function($scope, portfolioFactory) {
    $scope.PortfolioItems = portfolioFactory.getResponse();
    console.log($scope.PortfolioItems);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$http.get( ... );
```

Returns a [promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

```
app.controller("PortfolioCtrl", function($scope, portfolioFactory) {
    portfolioFactory.getResponse().then(function(response) {
        $scope.PortfolioItems = response.data;
    })
});
```

Will work.

In older versions of Angular `$scope.PortfolioItems = portfolioFactory.getResponse();`
would have worked too, but in newer versions Angular does not automatically unwrap promises anymore.

A promise is basically an alternate and nicer way of handling async action (a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)). 
Rather than using callbacks in a regular fashion you can put your callbacks in a queue with `promise.then( callback )`. Then whenever the deferred.resolve method is called, the callbacks are called with the results. If the promise already is resolved before the callbacks where queued they are immediately called with the cached data. Much nicer than doing `query( callback )` code that quite often turns into [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

FYI you could rather do this, as the result of any `$http` call is a promise already:

```
app.factory('portfolioFactory', function ($http) {
    var obj = {};

    obj.getResponse = function(){
        return $http.get('./../includes/portfolio/db_access.php').then(function(data){
           console.log(data);
           return data; //Return data further up the chain.
        });
    }
    return obj;
});
```

Comment: I'm still not able to use `$scope.PortfolioItems` as a data bound variable. I have an ng-repeat for the variable, though it's not loading anything.

Comment: Does it output anything in console?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to invoke the "then" function to get to your data.

```
app.controller("PortfolioCtrl", function($scope, portfolioFactory) {
    $scope.PortfolioItems = portfolioFactory.getResponse();

    $scope.PortfolioItems.then(function(results){
        console.log(results);
    };
});
```

It might spell it out to label things like this....

```
app.controller("PortfolioCtrl", function($scope, portfolioFactory) {
    $scope.PortfolioItems = null;
    var fetchPortfolioItems = portfolioFactory.getResponse();

    fetchPortfolioItems.then(function(results){
        $scope.PortfolioItems = results;
        console.log($scope.PortfolioItems);
    };
});
```